# Зачем нужны шаблонизаторы (компонент view в MVC)?

Tags: java, c#, python, любой-язык

Сейчас делаю небольшой проект с использованием `MVC` фреймворка `Django` на `python`. В любом `MVC` `view` представляется в виде какого-нибудь шаблонизатора. Например, в `java` это `jsp`, `freemarker` и т.д.

Не очень понимаю зачем это надо. Ведь бычно данные подтягиваются `ajax`-запросами, а генерировать страницу на сервере дорого по времени. Обмен между фронтендом и бекэндом происходит через json'ы. Зачем тогда нужен шаблонизатор ?

В смысле, не легче было бы отдавать статику каким-нибудь `nginx` или `apache`, а все данные с сервера получать `json`'ами ?

Comment: Что насчет клиентов, у которых нет мощного устройства (например, не топовые телефоны)? В этом случае рендеринг на стороне клиента может занять больше времени, особенно учитывая, что для этого понадобится доп. запрос к серверу. Что насчет поисковых систем - как они будут индексировать содержимое страниц (не разбираюсь в этом деле, но всё же)?

Comment: И вы оценивали аргументы "за" и "против" в статьях, которые можно найти в Гугле по запросу "client side vs server side rendering"? Если вдруг никто здесь не отпишется, рассчитывать придётся на них.

Comment: @Regent, обязательно посмотрю. Спасибо.

Comment: @Regent Просто дело еще и в том, что в большинстве случаев `application`-серверы работает по приницу многопоточности или со множеством процессов, как например, `gunicorn` и не предназначены изначально для отдачи статики. Для этого есть всякие асинхронные фронтендные серверы, типа `nginx`. Получается, что схема с шаблонизаторами в общем случае будет работать дольше.

Comment: "В среднем по больнице", возможно, и дольше. Вопрос в том, будут ли сайтом пользоваться люди со слабыми (например, старыми JavaME) телефонами, и если "да", то плевать на них или нет. Я не приближен к Web-у и подобных тестов не устраивал, так что ничего утверждать не берусь. Мысль в том, что стоит рассматривать плюсы и минусы обоих подходов и выбирать тот, который кажется вам лучше. При этом для других людей и других проектов лучше может показаться другой подход, так что вряд ли один из подходов вымрет в обозримом будущем. Рассмотрите плюсы рендеринга на стороне сервера, а не только его минусы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Паттерн MVC впервые был описан работником компании Xerox, SmallTalk программистом Трюгве Ринскаугом в 1978 году. Паттерн относится не только к веб приложениям!.

JSP если я не ошибаюсь был принят в 2002 году.

AJAX - 2005 Год

> VIEW(представление) - это наглядное отображение содержащихся в модели данных.
>   Подмножество модели содержится в отдельном представлении, таким
>   образом, представление действует в качестве фильтра для данных модели.
>   Пользователь взаимодействует с данными модели с помощью предлагаемого
>   представлением наглядного отображения и  обращается к бизнес-логике,
>   которая, в свою очередь, воздействует на данные модели

Исходя и вышесказанного view может быть все что угодно, что предоставляет наглядное отображение для взаимодействия с пользователем, будь то сотня jsp страниц или же SAP на ajax'е. Что лучше выбрать для реализовывать представление - это уже вопрос к спецификациям самого проекта.

Comment: Вопрос в том, что на дворе 2017 - шаблонизаторы без `ajax` (или с частичным `ajax`) все еще существуют и здравствуют. Почему ? Разве одна технология не замещает полностью другую ? Например, согласно википедии: "В настоящее время разрабатывается ASP.NET MVC 6, как часть ASP.NET Core; 27 июня 2016 года состоялся выход версии 1.0.0". Там тоже шаблонизатор. Почему ?

Comment: @faoxis так ведь не бывает универсальных решений. В каких-то ситуациях лучше подходит один вариант, в каких-то - другой. На мой взгляд, нужно заниматься оценкой и профилированием конкретного проекта (или даже страницы) для выяснения какой подход лучше всего работает в данной ситуации. Причем тестировать нужно не только на мощных компьютерах разработчиков, но и на реальных устройстах, с которых пользователи будут просматривать сайт.

Comment: Присоединяюсь к комментарию @Regent. И хотелось бы добавить что проекты имеют свой жизненный цикл после релиза и сложные корпоративные решения никто не будет переписывать под чистую на новые технологии которые выходят каждые 5 лет.